# How can I read data from a PLIST in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode6, plist

i'm facing a problem with reading data from a plist file using swift
[image: my .plist file]

my code:

```
        let Chapterpath = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("chapterMapping", ofType: "plist")
    let dict2 = NSDictionary(contentsOfFile: Chapterpath!)
    let chaptername = dict2?.objectForKey("chapterName")
    let chapterNumber = dict2?.objectForKey("pageNumber")
```

next i'm trying to add plist data to an array, should i simply use

```
var myArray = [chapterName]
```

my question: is the code above correct?
or im i missing something
and when i tried to print plist data using println((chapterName))
i got an error

thank you

Comment: How to ask a question: What's the problem? Did you try it? What did you try, exactly? When you did, what happened? Was it what you wanted? If not, what's the difference between what happened and what you wanted?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, your `Root` object in the plist is an `NSArray` not a `NSDictionary`.

Second, if you want to use KVC on Foundation Collections (I don't believe this works with Swift's Array) you need to call `valueForKeyPath`.

```
let chapterPath = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("chapterMapping", ofType: "plist")
if let arrayOfItems: [AnyObject] = NSArray(contentsOfFile: chapterPath!) {
    let chapterNames: [String] = arrayOfItems.valueForKeyPath("chapterName") as NSArray as [String]
    let pageNumbers: [Int] = arrayOfItems.valueForKeyPath("pageNumber") as NSArray as [Int]
}
```

Third, the swift-y way of doing this would be with the `map` function, but `arrayOfItems` would need to be a strongly-defined type and it might be more work than it's worth.  Example:

```
let array: [ChapterMetaData] = // define it here
let chapterImages = array.map { $0.chapterImage }
```

Answer (score 1):

As you say you have an array with multiple element. objectForKey does not search the hall tree levels and gets you the first one with the name. you have multiple values a loop must be envolved. Try the following:

```
var Chapterpath:NSString = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("chapterMapping", ofType: "plist");
var chapters:NSArray = NSArray(contentsOfFile: Chapterpath);

for chapter in chapters {
    let chaptername = chapter["chapterName"]
    let chapterNumber = chapter["pageNumber"]
    println(chaptername);
}
```

Comment: var chapters:NSArray = NSArray(contentsOfFile: Chapterpath). i got an error: 
extra arguments 'contentsOfFile' in call

Answer (score 1):

Use following code to read `Plist` data to `NSArray`:

```
let path = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource(plistName, ofType: "plist")
var list = NSArray(contentsOfFile: path!) as [[String:String]]
```

Answer (score 1):

Simplest way to parse the AppConfig.plist file in project:

```
var dictionaryObj: NSDictionary?
if let filePath = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("AppConfig", ofType: "plist") 
{
    dictionaryObj = NSDictionary(contentsOfFile: filePath)
}
if let dict = dictionaryObj 
{
    //parse it as NSDictionary
}
else
{
    //dictionaryObj is nil or doesn't contain anything.
}
```

Comment: Working in all Swift projects. I have executed this code in Swift 2.0. (XCode 7.1.0)

Answer (score 0):

**You can use NSArray if `Plist` `Root` is Array:**

```
let path = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("OrderHelper", ofType: "plist")
let myArray = NSArray(contentsOfFile: path!)
```

**You can use NSDictionary if `Plist` `Root` is Dictionary:**

```
let path = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("OrderHelper", ofType: "plist") {
let myDict = NSDictionary(contentsOfFile: path!)
```