# MacOS Swift, how to read another .app/url info.plist

Tags: swift, macos

I have listed the apps installed on the user machine via swift in the following manner:

```swift
public func getAllApplications() -> [Application] {
    do {
      let runningApps = NSWorkspace.shared.runningApplications
      let localApplicationUrl = try FileManager.default.url(for: .applicationDirectory, in: .localDomainMask, appropriateFor: nil, create: false)
      let localApplicationUrls = getApplicationUrlsAt(localApplicationUrl)
      let systemApplicationUrl = try FileManager.default.url(for: .applicationDirectory, in: .systemDomainMask, appropriateFor: nil, create: false)
      let systemApplicationsUrls = getApplicationUrlsAt(systemApplicationUrl)
      let userApplicationUrl = try FileManager.default.url(for: .applicationDirectory, in: .userDomainMask, appropriateFor: nil, create: false)
      let personalApplicationUrls = getApplicationUrlsAt(userApplicationUrl)

      let allApplicationUrls =
      localApplicationUrls + systemApplicationsUrls + personalApplicationUrls + fixedApps

      var applications = [Application]()

      for url in allApplicationUrls {
        let resourceKeys: [URLResourceKey] = [.isExecutableKey, .isApplicationKey]
        let resourceValues = try url.resourceValues(forKeys: Set(resourceKeys))
        if resourceValues.isExecutable ?? false {
          let name = url.deletingPathExtension().lastPathComponent
          let urlStr = url.absoluteString
          let firstRunning = runningApps.first(where: {
            return $0.bundleURL?.absoluteString == urlStr
            
          })
          applications.append(Application(name: name, url: urlStr, isRunning: firstRunning != nil))
        }
      }

      return applications
    } catch {
      print("Could not get applications! \(error)")
      return []
    }
  }

struct Application {
  var name: String
  var url: String
  var isRunning: Bool
}
```

I would like to add the bundle name (e.g. `com.apple.xcode` or `com.microsoft.vscode`) to the `Application` struct. Is there (easy) way to read the `Info.plist` given the URLs?

Another point: I want to read the `Info.plist` because there is other useful information in there, such as registered file types and linked domains.

Comment: Which part is giving you trouble, in particular? `Info.plist` is really just a `plist` like any other, you can load it into a dict and fish out whatever keys you're interested in. As for looking up " registered file types and linked domains", I'd recommend using the proper APIs for those if possible, rather than trying to infer it by reading from Application bundles

Comment: By the way, it looks like you're trying to guess the running app' bundle locations by scanning a few predefined dirs. This is error-prone: it'll give both excess results (when multiple copies of an app exist in multiple places, each of them will always be returned, even if only one of them is actually running) and missing results (in cases where an app is run from somewhere else, e.g. from the downloads folder). Lucky for you, you can just ask it for its [`bundleURL`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nsrunningapplication/1535500-bundleurl) and take the guesswork out of it.

Comment: hmm interesting, thanks for the tips, I could not find any other API to read all the installed applications on the machine of the user. As for duplicated entries, it is fine because if the user has more than one version in different folders it is ok to show them.

Comment: As for reading the .plist, I just don't know how to access the contents of the file described in the URLs and actually load the plist into a variable or reads its contents in swift code. It's nothing fancy I'm just not a Swift dev.

Comment: "I could not find any other API to read all the installed applications on the machine of the user." Launch services has some private APIs that do a similar thing, but in general, Applications aren't "installed", so asking for all "installed applications" doesn't really make sense on macOS. A thorough/correct answer would involve scanning the entire system from `.app` bundles (or using the Spotlight index to find them faster). What you're doing by checking `NSWorkspace.shared.runningApplications` is fine, it's just searching in those applications folders manually after that's the odd part

Comment: "As for reading the .plist, I just don't know how to access the contents of the file described in the URLs and actually load the plist into a variable or reads its contents in swift code." There's a fair number of existing questions on this which I think you'd find helpful, e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27345617/how-can-i-read-data-from-a-plist-in-swift Search is your friend.

Comment: As for checking which applications are used to open certain extensions or URL schemes, I wouldn't do this from the Info.plists at all. You're starting from a limited subset of applications (which excluded non-running applications, or applications outside those 3 folders you check), so you'll miss result. It's better to instead query Launch Services for the apps for particular UTIs or URL schemes, and have it give you a known-complete list. See https://rderik.com/blog/managing-uti-and-url-schemes-via-launch-services-api-from-swift/